# how to user login my site with their facebook username and password.?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

My site have login facility. To login once have to registration in my site. If user dont want to registration in my site. then user can login with their facebook username and password. to access my site.. How this possible..?

Comment: Read about Facebook API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with **Facebook SDK** [it is a code, you can get this from internet].

1. First create facebook application on developer.facebook.com
2. Use its credentials in facebook SDK file.

Comment: In that after login page redirect to my home page or not...?

Comment: You need to add return url in your facebook app while creating it. It will redirect you to your desired page after login.

Comment: Whenever you login with facebook it returns you array containing information regarding FB profile, which contains email, username etc. at first login attempted you should save that user to your database and on further attempts you should not. by this you can get username from your own database.

Comment: ok..
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
can possible to make saperate link of login and logout.  in facebook php sdk

Comment: Yes you can make separate link.

Comment: how it is possible.. Can u explain me. I have no idea hot to saperate fb sutolink.

Comment: What I am getting from your point is that you want separate button on your login page, Which submits the username and password on another page where you call FB api for finding user info on FB. If user exist on FB then make his/her entry in your database user table(if already exist in your DB then don't). also make his/her login session according to your user table id. In this way you can make user login with facebook account.

Comment: You exactly understand. I want to separate button. because. My project is based on smarty. So i confuse how to implement on smarty.

Comment: Ok JD but I am Zend Developer (MVC), don't have idea about smarty.